# Is there any CSS grid framework like blueprint, 960.gs specifically for mobile websites?

Tags: css, xhtml, mobile-website

Is there any CSS grid framework like blueprint, 960.gs specifically for mobile websites?

For `media="handheld"` and iphone both. With a good reset and Grid.

Comment: Is there a need for a `CSS` framework? Just include a reset like Eric Meyers and you should be good to go...

Answer (score 2):

**[CSS Grid](http://cssgrid.net/)** support for Mobile version

Try **resize** your browser to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check out 960 Grid on jQuery-Mobile:

http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/

Answer (score 0):

no, there are some mobile css resets but even css reset is too much on a mobile site as it must be optimized for speed and as less as possible bandwidth